# QGraphicsItem - Problemas para obtener tamaño con zoom

Tags: c++, qt

tengo el siguiente problema que realmente no le encuentro la solucion. Tengo un QGraphicsItem, que tiene un tamaño de 2000mts X 2000mts escalados en la pantalla. En cierto momento, hago un zoom, con lo cual lo que esté dibujado en ese QGraphicsItem se ve mas grande...ahora bien, como hago yo para saber en un determinado momento, despues de hacer varias veces zoom, cuandos metros de ancho y alto estoy viendo???...porque si le pregunto al QGraphicsItem siempre me dice 2000x2000...pero al haber hecho zoom, yo estoy viendo menos metros en pantalla. No puedo poner el codigo real porque tiene monton de otras cosas, pero voy a poner una aproximacion.

```
GridFarmGraph *grid = new GridFarmGraph(view->getWidth(), view->getHeight());

FarmGraph *farmGraph = new FarmGraph(2000);
farmGraph->setTransform(QTransform().scale(view->getWidth() / 2000, view->getHeight() / 2000);
farmGraph->setParentItem(grid);
```

GridFarmGraph es un graphicsitem que esta por debajo, del tamño de la Vista. FarmGraph es un graphicsitem que es hijo GridFarmGraph y está escalado para que en la pantalla pueda simular 2000mts de ancho por 2000mts de alto...hasta ahi todo bien...si clickeo con el mouse me dice realmente en que parte de esos 2000x2000 clickie!. Pero cuando hago zoom, obviamente en pantalla, al agrandarse todo, veo menos de 2000 x 2000 mts...lo que necesito es saber cuanto estoy viendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase [`QGraphicsItem`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.htm) tiene un par de métodos (`mapFromScene` y `mapToScene`) que te permiten conocer la relación entre el escenario original (sin escalar) y tu escala actual.

Por ejemplo, si queremos saber la superficie visualizada realmente podemos coger las coordenadas de las esquinas del widget:

```
QPointF esqSupIzq = QPointF(0,0); // Coordenada superior izquierda = origen
QPointF esqInfDer = QPointF(widget->width(),widget->height());

QPointF mapSupIzq = widget->mapToScene(esqSupIzq);
QPointF mapInfDer = widget->mapToScene(esqInfDer);

double totalWidth  = mapInfDer.x() - mapSupIzq.x();
double totalHeight = mapInfDer.y() - mapSupIzq.y();
```

Si, en cambio, necesitas saber las coordenadas reales de un punto seleccionado por el usuario:

```
QPointF seleccionUsuario = /* ... */;
QPointF puntoEscena = widget->MapToScene(seleccionUsuario);
```

Comment: Lo que pones como widget, es un QGraphicsItem y no tiene una propiedad width, lo que tiene es un boundingRect que si tiene un width y siempre es 2000x2000 por lo que siempre me dá los mismos valores por mas que haga zoom y no me dá los valores que estoy viendo por pantalla

Comment: Pero el `QGraphicsItem` estará embebido en algún widget para poder presentárselo al usuario... no? quizás un [`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)? Revisa este último y verás que sí que tiene `width()` y `height()`